# meson.build:97:0: ERROR: Subproject directory not found and glib.wrap file not found

Tags: python, linux, wireshark

I am trying to install Wireshark. There is a dependency of atk package. I downloaded atk-2.32.0 from net. atk-2.32.0 could only be install by meson.

Below are the steps I followed for installation.

1. Downloaded atk
2. Download meson
3. Moved to atk directory.
4. Used command

```
../meson-0.50.0/meson.py _build .  
>>However it is give this error:  
>>"meson.build:97:0: ERROR: Subproject directory not found and glib.wrap   
>>file not found."
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: And how this is related to atk4 (PHP library)?

Answer (score 0):

To add a Meson `subproject`, you need to create [a `.wrap` file](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrap-dependency-system-manual.html) and put it in the `subprojects` directory of the main Meson project.

If the `subprojects` directory doesn't exist in your project directory, you need to create it. Then create a file in the `subprojects` directory called `glib.wrap` with the following contents:

```
[wrap-git]
url = https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib.git

[provide]
dependency_names = glib-2.0, gobject-2.0, gio-2.0
```

This extremely basic `.wrap` file *should* work, but if you're shipping a project (or a cloned repository requires it) you may prefer specifying a given version of GLib by downloading a versioned `.wrap` file from Meson's [WrapDB](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrapdb-projects.html) (scroll down to `glib`).

I'm extremely new to Meson subprojects, but it *seems* like the `.wrap` file should have been included in the cloned repository in the first place? Also on Linux at least GLib should "just work", or at least it should be available with a `compiler.find_library()` call in your `meson.build` like so:

```py
deps = [
    meson.get_compiler('c').find_library('glib'),
    ...
]

executable(
    meson.project_name(),
    dependencies: deps,
    ...
)
```

Please sound off in the comments if these don't quite work. I'm posting an answer here because this is the top DuckDuckGo search result for this error message, but in my case I was trying to add a different `subproject` to a project of my own, so it would have been quite a bit more work for me to test this particular example.